# AVAudioplayer plays data only for a second

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, alamofire

i am trying to play Songs from soundcloud. Since the iOS-SDK has been discontinued, i have to do all of the authentication and streaming stuff myself. When streaming a song, i basically create a stream with Alamofire and parse the receiving data into an AVAudioplayer instance. It then plays the sound for a second and pauses itself. What am i missing?

```
class SoundcloudPlayer: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    var clientProvider: SoundcloudConnectorProvider!
    var track: SoundcloudTrack?
    private var stream: Request?
    private var audioData = NSMutableData()
    private var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func play(){
        if let client = clientProvider?.currentClient() where client.hasUnexpiredAccessToken() && track != nil{
            stream = client.request(.GET, self.track!.url!).stream({ (data) -> Void in
                self.audioData.appendData(data)
                if self.audioPlayer == nil{
                    do{ self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: self.audioData)} catch {print("error") }
                    self.audioPlayer.delegate = self
                    self.audioPlayer.play()
                }
                print(self.audioPlayer.data?.length)
            }).progress({ (read, total, expected) -> Void in
                Async.main(block: { () -> Void in
                //print("\(total)/\(expected)")
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use AVAudioPlayer since it's only for playing local file.
Instead, you can use audio queue, to play a stream of audio, or audio unit, a lower level API.
Since the audio stream is a "stream", you can try CFReadStream/NSInputStream, or Audio File Stream to read data continously, not just by "get".
So for example, you can use CFReadStream+Audio Queue to play the sound. It's difficult, good luck!